# Add class and change text on radio button when selected

Tags: jquery, select, radio-button, checked

I am trying to change the text on a radio button once it's been selected. I have it working so I add a class to the parent if the radio button is checked, now just need the part to change the text of the span inside the parent (I want the text "Select" to change to "Selected" if the radio button is checked). Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //add the Selected class to the checked radio button
    $('input:checked').parent().addClass("selected");
    //If another radio button is clicked, add the select class, and remove it from the previously selected radio
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("selected");
        $('input:checked').parent().addClass("selected");
    });

});
            <td><div class="selectBtn">
                <input type="radio" name="group1" id="one" value="Falcon Air Trust">
                <span class="selectTxt">Select</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="selectBtn">
                <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Atlantic Aviation">
                <span class="selectTxt">Select</span></div></td>
            <td><div class="selectBtn">
                <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Reliance Aviation">
                Select</div></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //add the Selected class to the checked radio button
    $('input:checked').parent().addClass("selected");
    //If another radio button is clicked, add the select class, and remove it from the previously selected radio
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("selected").find("span").html("Select");
        $('input:checked').parent().addClass("selected").find("span").html("Selected");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

or alternatively

http://jsfiddle.net/62DhL/1/